# Convergence of $ L^{p} $-integrals implies convergence in $ L^{p} $-norm?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Let $E$ be a measurable set, 
$\{ f_n \}$ and $f$ are in $L^p(E)$ such that $f_n \to f$ pointwise a.e.

If $\lim \|f_n \|_p = \| f \|_p$, 
is it true that $\lim \| f_n - f \|_p = 0$?

I have tried using Generalised Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, 
for all $n$, 
$|f_n-f|^p \leq g_n:=(|f_n|+|f|)^p$, 
then $g_n \to g:=2^p|f|^p$ pointwise a.e. 
But how to show $\lim \int g_n = \int g$?

Thank you!!

Comment: As I recall this is true if $f_n$ are all nonnegative, and false in general. But I have forgotten the counterexample. You might look into the Vitali Convergence Theorem, which provides a necessary and sufficient condition for convergence in $L^p$. In particular, in view of the details of the Vitali convergence theorem, whether $E$ has finite measure might be relevant.

Comment: True for $1<p<\infty$ ... such $L_p$ have "uniformly convex" unit ball.

Comment: You must exclude $ p = \infty $, otherwise $ \left( \chi_{[0,n]} \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $ would be a counterexample for $ E = [0,\infty) $.

Comment: HINT: Look in the book "Analysis" by Lieb and Loss. The theorem "Missing term in Fatou's lemma" (§1.9 in the second edition) is there exactly to treat problems like the one you have at hand.

Comment: Thank you GEdgar for reminding me that 1<=p<+inf.

Comment: Thank Negro for telling me "the missing term"(Lieb's Lemma). I have read it and known how they are related. The proof essentially applies Fatou's Lemma and (Not Generalised one) Lebesque Dominated Convergence Theorem. While I have one more follow-up question since my exercise asks me to try to apply GLDCT as a hint. Would there be a more direct way?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** First use Hölder’s Inequality to get $ 2^{p - 1} (|f_{n}|^{p} + |f|^{p}) - |f_{n} - f|^{p} \ge 0 $, then write:
\begin{align}
  & ~ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \int_{E} |f_{n} - f|^{p} ~ \mathrm{d}{\mu} \\
= & ~ \lim_{n \to \infty}
      \int_{E} 2^{p - 1} (|f_{n}|^{p} + |f|^{p}) ~ \mathrm{d}{\mu} -
      \liminf_{n \to \infty}
      \int_{E} \left[ 2^{p - 1} (|f_{n}|^{p} + |f|^{p}) - |f_{n} - f|^{p} \right]
      \mathrm{d}{\mu}.
\end{align}
Finally, use Fatou’s Lemma.

Comment: I have tried using your hint. However, this would results in lim sup int(|fn-f|^p)>=0.  Seems it cannot solve the problem.

Comment: I reversed the sign of ineqality, I have got it now! Thanks! However, I do not know how to apply Holder's inequality to prove the inequality you mentioned at the beginning.