# $ L^p $ convergence if and only if convergence of integral

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Consider a finite measure space and assume $ f_n \to f $ in $ L^p $, that is $ \int |f_n - f|^p \to 0 $. The claim in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3022527/if-x-n-to-x-in-lp-is-ex-np-to-exp-true?noredirect=1&lq=1) is that $ \int |f_n|^p \to \int |f|^p $. In there, the OP said that if $ f_n $ and $ f $ are nonnegative, then the claim follows directly from Minkowski Theorem, but I don't see the reason for that. Can someone explain that part?

The Minkowski Theorem that I assume the OP mentioned is 
$$ \left( \int |f + g|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \leq \left( \int |f|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} + \left( \int |g|^p \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}. $$
Also, is the converse direction $ \int |f_n|^p \to \int |f|^p $ implies $ \int |f_n - f|^p \to 0 $ true?

Comment: For the converse, it is obviously false. Recall for example that $\int |f|^p=\int |-f|^p$. So if this were true you would have at the same time $\int |f_n-f|^p \to 0$ and $\int |f_n+f|^p \to 0$, which is impossible.

Comment: Take a look at Riesz's Theorem. If $f_n$ converges almost surely to $f$  (all of these in $L^p$ ) then the double implication holds. I don't know if it's of any help though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The triangle inequality in used is that $\bigg|\|f_{n}\|_{L^{p}}-\|f\|_{L^{p}}\bigg|^{p}\leq\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{p}}^{p}$, so $\|f_{n}\|_{L^{p}}\rightarrow\|f\|_{L^{p}}$ but then it also holds that $\|f_{n}\|_{L^{p}}^{p}\rightarrow\|f\|_{L^{p}}^{p}$.

The other direction is not correct, consider $f_{n}=n\chi_{[0,1/n]}$ and $f=\chi_{[0,1]}$, then $\|f_{n}\|_{L^{1}}=1$ and $\|f\|_{L^{1}}=1$ but $(f_{n}-f)(x)=n-1$ for $x\in[0,1/n]$ and $(f_{n}-f)(x)=1$ for $x\in(1/n,1]$ and zero otherwise, then $\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{1}}\rightarrow 2$.